# Max of 10 items due to "View The Full list" button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

link = http://fortune.com/worlds-most-admired-companies/2016/

So, I want all the 'href' that are inside a div with a known 'class name'
I could not get away with this:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

raw = urllib.request.urlopen('http://fortune.com/worlds-most-admired-companies/2016/')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(raw, 'lxml')

listdiv = soup.find('div', clsss_="company-franchise-result-content current")

for url in listdiv.find_all('a'):
    print(url.get('href'))﻿
```

I have previously used:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(a.get('href'))
```

It **works** but only returns 10 items, from apple to general electric. even when I feed it the link I get when I click the "View the Full list" button.
I have 0 idea of how JSON works but it looks this is heading that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The complete data is actually there, in the HTML*. It is just inside a JavaScript object inside a `script` tag. You can locate this `script` tag, get it's text, extract the JSON string, load it into a Python data structure with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and get the desired data:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: import json

In [3]: import re

In [4]: url = "http://fortune.com/worlds-most-admired-companies/2016/"

In [5]: response = requests.get(url)

In [6]: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")   

In [7]: pattern = re.compile(r"var fortune_wp_vars = ({.*?});", re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

In [8]: script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)   

In [9]: data = json.loads(pattern.search(script.get_text()).group(1))  

In [10]: companies = data["bootstrap"]["franchise"]["filtered_sorted_data"]

In [11]: for company in companies:
    ...:     print(company["title"])
    ...:     
Apple
Alphabet
...
Yum Brands
ZF Friedrichshafen
Zurich Insurance Group
```

Comment: Nice, what documentation can I see to instead of getting the title get the link for each company

Comment: @Trotus just explore what other keys the `company` dictionary has.